# How Could Choosing the best friend in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Greetings I am New to create applications for facebook, at this point I would like to make an application, which select the best friend, ie the person with whom you speak more for chat, e been researching and testing a coupon, no e found way to do it, if they are so kind as to tell me or give me or example would appreciate much!

**I repeat:** An Application Where Choose best friend, best friend would be the one with whom you have more chat on facebook

Comment: please post what you have tried so far and we will steer you in the right direction. we won't spoonfeed.

Answer (score 0):

**It took until now this,**

```
require('src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => 'ID','secret' => 'SECRET','cookie' => true,));   
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}

$statuses = $facebook->api('/me/statuses');
```

**as I can know who is the person with whom I speak more chat**

Answer (score 0):

You would need to get the permission "read_mailbox" approved for this, but Facebook will definitely not approve it:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client
>   on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example,
>   Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In
>   addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this
>   permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_mailbox

Meaning, what you are trying to achieve is not possible.

Comment: I know an app, which is working and I am commenting. chooses the person has messages in chat facebook, and shows him as a best friend

Comment: an old v1.0 app. it will stop working after april 2015, when those old apps will get upgraded to v2.0 and have to go through the review process too.